# Is there a simple MySQL query to add a bunch of values to specified rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, import, addition

I have a MySQL table with several columns, including `id` and `count`. I just got an Excel spreadsheet with the same item `id`s paired with numbers that must be added to the `count` for each row.

For instance, here's a subset of the data, showing only the relevant columns:

```
| id  | count |
|-----+-------|
| ... | ...   |
| 348 | 165   |
| 347 | 364   |
| 346 | 381   |
| 345 | 6017  |
| ... | ...   |
```

And this the data from the Excel spreadsheet:

```
| id  | add   |
|-----+-------|
| ... | ...   |
| 348 | 3,766 |
| 347 | 386   |
| 346 | 860   |
| 345 | 0     |
| ... | ...   |
```

I want to combine the `count` and `add` fields for each `id` so that the `count` is updated like so, leaving all other columns in the table untouched:

```
| id  | count |
|-----+-------|
| ... | ...   |
| 348 | 3931  |
| 347 | 750   |
| 346 | 1241  |
| 345 | 6017  |
| ... | ...   |
```

I know MySQL can do it, but I don't know what the steps are. What format should I export the Excel data? CSV? TSV? How do I read the "adjustment" file in to MySQL? What is the syntax for this kind of UPDATE command?

Comment: Will the spreadsheet always contain only `id`s existing in the database or can it have new `id`s as well? If the latter, do you want the new `id`s to be added to the table?

Comment: That's a shrewd question, thanks! The spreadsheet only contains items already in the database. Now that the database is updated, we hopefully won't have to keep two sets of data from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this in a couple of steps:

1. [`CREATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) a `TEMPORARY TABLE`.
2. [`LOAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) the data into the temporary table
3. [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) the original table, using a  `JOIN` against the temporary one.

`CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE` syntax is straightforward. It's just like creating a table, but it goes away when your session ends. The table format should match the columns which you want to update. This can be accomplished simply using the `CREATE ... (SELECT...)` syntax, eg:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `data_to_load` (
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `count`
    FROM
        `table_to_update`
    WHERE
        0
);
```

This will create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` called `data_to_load`, consisting of exactly the same format as the `table_to_update` columns `id` and `count`. The `WHERE 0` will never match, so it just copies the *format* of the table, not the data.

Next, `LOAD`ing the data. The format isn't picky, you just need to specify it. For standard CSV format as used by Excel, the command would be:

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'exported_data.csv'
    INTO TABLE `data_to_load`
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        ESCAPED BY '"'
(
    `id`,
    `count`
);
```

Finally, `UPDATE` the existing data, by `JOIN`ing with your new table:

```
UPDATE
    `table_to_update`
    INNER JOIN `data_to_load`
        ON `data_to_load`.`id` = `table_to_update`.`id`
SET
    `table_to_update`.`count` = `table_to_update`.`count` + `data_to_load`.`count`
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Import your values from the csv using a technique like [this one](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/). Once you have that table, try this. If your original table is called "counts", and your new table is called "adds", this query will show you what the combination will be:

```
select a.id,a.count,b.add,a.count + b.add as sum from counts as a, adds as b where a.id = b.id;
```

If it's doing what you want, then update:

```
update counts set counts.count = counts.count + adds.add where counts.id = adds.id;
```